# Storing coefficients/variable importance from a loop in a dataframe/list/matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, r-caret

I will be running a bunch of different models on a dataset in a loop and I'm seeking for a way to place the variable importance/coeffecients into a data frame for reference afterwards.

I envision a dataframe/matrix with the model name as column headers and the list of all potential variables as the row names (or vice versa).

```
 library(MASS)
 library(caret)

 #which to use?
 coef_df = data.frame()
 coef_list = list()

 for (i in 0:1){
 subset = Boston[which(Boston$chas==i),]
 ctrl =trainControl(method='cv',number=5)
 rf_model = train(medv ~. , data=subset, trControl=ctrl, method='rf')
 gbm_model = train(medv ~. , data=subset, trControl=ctrl, method='gbm')
 #where does this go   =varImp(rf_model)
 #where does this go   =varImp(gbm_model)
  }
```

I think that is more or less 90% of any coding/typing I would need to do, I just don't know who to place the variable importance values into the correct bucket in a data frame/matrix, since each time in the varImp call the variables will be in a different order - even if they might be the same here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Central rule in `R`: forget the `for` - it is forbidden.

Now, how you can do this elegantly with `data.table` giving only the results for the `gbm` method:

```
gbm.DT <- Boston.DT[
  , {
    gbm_model <- train(medv ~. , data=.SD, trControl=ctrl, method='gbm')
    varImp(gbm_model)$importance
  }
  , keyby = (chas1 = chas)
  ]
```

Comment: I'm sure that this is a more elegant way, but I'm not really sure how this is working and how to mess around with it to meet further changes I might run into.

Comment: Take the basic data.table course for free at Datacamp:
https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-table-data-manipulation-r-tutorial

Comment: `for` is not the problem *usually*. It's what goes inside the loop. data.table utilises `for` with `set` for example.

Comment: @Arun, if you know what you are doing, by all means do use it. However, people using 'for' usually misuse it.